# Not able to use typo3 frontend edit

Tags: typo3

I'm trying to edit frontend of my website using typo3. I'm entering /typo3 to the domain name but it shows page not fount! Can someone tell me what could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you're right with it, but there seems to be a change by the web server. You should ask the administrator where to look for the TYPO3 backend.

Comment: Yes but I'm running typo3 on local server, I'm using xampp